Are 2" holes in 4" studs inside exterior wall a problem?
I recently had a 100 amp subpanel installed in my garage. The job's already finished but I pulled the drywall off to run a new circuit and saw he bored out some pretty huge holes...
I read up to 60% of the depth of the stud is an ok hole diameter for interior studs, but for an exterior wall I thought code only alllows 40% and it's a long run inluding 4x4 and 8x4 studs. No stud shoes installed or anything.
This is a 2 story, 3100 sqft home in the SF Bay Area. Should I be worried?
Pics here, if it helps: https://imgur.com/a/s6l9Pzm

Check the SF Bay regulations.

What are these 4x4 and 8x4 studs you're talking about? How many studs were bored? Please revise to describe the situation more clearly.

Earthquake zone you want local experts to answer.  You are under different codes from the rest of us, usually more, so what is good/okay for us is not for you.
